# Magento: Clicking on add to cart open a order form. After submitting form redirect to add to cart page

Tags: magento

I am working on one magento site. What client need after clicking on Add To Cart button a prescription form will be opened.

After filling prescription form it redirect to Add to cart page. On Cart page product listing prescription that user added should be display with product.

Can anyone guide me how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

1) Switch the addtocart url with a javascript pop-up that opens.

2) Do the addtocart using ajax.

3) Show form in pop-up

4) When filled in do ajax post to controller that saves the items to the quote-item (setData).

5) Redirect to cart when this succeeds

6) Display custom data in the renderer using getData.

I guess this flow will put you in the right direction?

Comment: Switch the addtocart url with a javascript pop-up that opens. My site is running look like when user click on any product detail page will open in popup.